# How to make a simple bar graph and not stacked bar graph with Flot Charts?

Tags: javascript, flot, bar-chart

I'm rendering a bar chart with Flot charts. It's working fine. The following is the code:

```
var d1 = [
            [1,20],
            [2,30],
            [3,15],
            [4,45],
            [5,79]
            ];


                $.plot($("#mychart"), [d1], {
                grid: {
                        show: true,
                        clickable: true, 
                        hoverable: true

                },
                    series: {
                        stack: 0,

                        bars: {
                            show: true,
                            barWidth: 0.6,
                            fill: 0.6,
                            align:'center'
                        }
                    },

                colors: ["#F4A70C"]

                });
```

My data is fetched dynamically from the server. Even that is working fine. The problem is I'm using the following commands to redraw the graph:

```
            flot.setData(data);
            flot.setupGrid();
            flot.draw();
```

The output I get is a stacked bar graph. I want a new bar graph to be rendered everytime. I've set stack=0, but that doesn't seem to affect anything.
Please guide me.

Comment: Have you tried just calling `plot` again to redraw the graph?

Comment: That should do the trick. But folks say that it's not that effective to call plot again & again. So I was wondering if I can just redraw it like I did for the line graphs. :(

Comment: I've never had a problem with just recalling `plot`. YMMV.

Comment: Actually, I'm using AngularJS & have a single directive that handles the redraw feature of multiple charts. So I was wondering if I can redraw the charts, the code will be neat. Or else, I'll have to re-write the redraw for the bar chart separately, just to call plot again. :(

Answer (score 3):

The stack plugin sees values other than null, undefined, and false as true.  So replace your zero with 'false' and you should be okay.

Comment: This is because you can make different stacks - say `stack:0` and `stack:1`

Comment: I removed the Stack plugin and it works now. Silly me. Thanks for the insight, @DNS. Thanks a lot.